# jarvis takes too long to respond

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am making jarvis using c#. I coded it and jarvis is taking too long to respond back once we say anything. It takes like 10-15 mins to respond back and sometimes it don't even respond back. I want jarvis to respond quickly as soon as I give speech commands.

```
 using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Speech.Recognition;
    using System.Speech.Synthesis;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Jarvis
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            SpeechRecognitionEngine _recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
            SpeechSynthesizer JARVIS = new SpeechSynthesizer();
            string QEvent;
            string ProcWindow;
            double timer = 10;
            int count = 1;
            Random rnd = new Random();
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                _recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
                _recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ashwini\Desktop\Jarvis\Jarvis\bin\Debug\commands.txt")))));
                _recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
                _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            }
            void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
            {
                int ranNum = rnd.Next(1, 10);
                string speech = e.Result.Text;
                switch (speech)
                {

                    case "hello":
                    case "hello jarvis":
                        if (ranNum < 6) { JARVIS.Speak("Hello sir"); }
                        else if (ranNum > 5) { JARVIS.Speak("Hello"); }
                        break;
                    case "goodbye":
                    case "goodbye jarvis":
                    case "close":
                    case "close jarvis":
                        JARVIS.Speak("Until next time");
                        Close();
                        break;
                    case "jarvis":
                        if (ranNum < 5) { QEvent = ""; JARVIS.Speak("Yes sir"); }
                        else if (ranNum > 4) { QEvent = ""; JARVIS.Speak("Yes?"); }
                        break;

                    //WEBSITES
                    case "open google":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/");
                        break;
                    case "open my facebook":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.facebook.com/");
                        break;
                    case "open gmail":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.google.com/gmail/");
                        break;

                    //SHELL COMMANDS
                    case "open this pc":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("This PC");
                        JARVIS.Speak("Loading");
                        break;

                    case "open my folder":
                        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("F:");
                        JARVIS.Speak("Loading");
                        break;

                    //CLOSE PROGRAMS
                    case "close this pc":
                        ProcWindow = "This PC";
                        StopWindow();
                        break;

                    //CONDITION OF DAY
                    case "what time is it":
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                        string time = now.GetDateTimeFormats('t')[0];
                        JARVIS.Speak(time);
                        break;
                    case "what day is it":
                        JARVIS.Speak(DateTime.Today.ToString("dddd"));
                        break;
                    case "whats the date":
                    case "whats todays date":
                        JARVIS.Speak(DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
                        break;

                    //OTHER COMMANDS
                    case "go fullscreen":
                        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
                        WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
                        TopMost = true;
                        JARVIS.Speak("expanding");
                        break;
                    case "exit fullscreen":
                        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
                        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        TopMost = false;
                        break;
                    case "switch window":
                        SendKeys.Send("%{TAB " + count + "}");
                        count += 1;
                        break;

                    case "out of the way":
                        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Normal || WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
                        {
                            WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
                            JARVIS.Speak("My apologies");
                        }
                        break;
                    case "come back":
                        if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                        {
                            JARVIS.Speak("Alright?");
                            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
                        }
                        break;
                    case "show commands":
                        string[] commands = (File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ashwini\Desktop\Jarvis\Jarvis\bin\Debug\commands.txt"));
                        JARVIS.Speak("Very well");
                        lstCommands.Items.Clear();
                        lstCommands.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.None;
                        lstCommands.Visible = true;
                        foreach (string command in commands)
                        {
                            lstCommands.Items.Add(command);
                        }
                        break;
                    case "hide listbox":
                        lstCommands.Visible = false;
                        break;

                }
            }

            private void StopWindow()
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

I dont know what is wrong with this code. Please help me out.

Comment: I have built this numerous times and it better to use `if statements` also I can give you a better way to do this if you want.

Comment: @Halonic Yaa I want the better way to do this and thanks for the tip

Comment: I am doing a tutorial on YouTube at some point today, it's going to be a brief tutorial the basics of getting speech set up and a few things on the commands and things like that. Also my channel is www.youtube.com/c/campnerd I would post it here but there is a lot of code. About 100+ lines of what I do in the program. Also my response time is about 0.849 of a second, now and the longest wait time in my full program has been 3 seconds. I will post back here when it's uploaded. However I have tutorials in C# as well on my channel.

Comment: Okay I subscribed your channel so I will know whenever you upload video on speech set up and commands. Thanks buddy!@Halonic

Comment: Here is the tutorial. https://youtu.be/BJkymbvxlJs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an in-depth tutorial on Speech Recognition see my tutorial https://youtu.be/BJkymbvxlJs

When using speech recognition you need to use the Async method. `Jarvis.SpeakAsync` the Async method will give continuing command and dictate.

Using only `Jarvis.Speak` you have to wait for the engine to complete. Example:

```
  Jarvis.Speak("this is what Jarvis will say after a  command is spoken");
```

Using `Jarvis.Speak` you can not execute any commands while it's synthesizing.

```
   Jarvis.SpeakAsync("this is what Jarvis will say after a command is spoken");
```

When using `Jarvis.SpeakAsync` this gives you the ability to pause, stop and/or interrupt the speech engine during the synthesis.

The tutorial link above shows a basic format of the `SpeakAsync` and how to use it in the application for speech recognition.

Answer (score 0):

the thing is it is still listening to the background noises even after we finish talking so just increase the energy threshold mine was 300 I changed it to 1000 now I just have to talk a little louder but the speech recognition is perfect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).